# Recognising that a subgoal is proved

Tags: isabelle

I would like to understand the state machine of the Isar Virtual Machine.

[Page 48 of Markus Wenzel's doctoral thesis](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/601724/601724.pdf#page=62) gives a good overview but does not detail its messages in the Output panel. It might well be a later addendum to the system.

I have a simple Isar proof:

```
theory Propositional
imports Main
begin

lemma nj2: assumes p: P and q: Q shows "P ∧ (Q ∧ P)"
proof - 
  from q p have qp: "Q ∧ P" by (rule conjI)
  from p qp show "P ∧ (Q ∧ P)" by (rule conjI)
qed
```

after the second `by (rule conjI)` the Output panel says

```
show (P::bool) /\ (Q::bool) /\ P 
Successful attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
  (P::bool) /\ (Q::bool) /\ P 
proof (state): depth 0

this:
  (P::bool) /\ (Q::bool) /\ P

goal:
No subgoals!
variables:
  P, Q :: bool
```

so it explicitly recognizes the solution of the goal. However, at the first `by (rule conjI)` it says

```
have qp: (Q::bool) /\ (P::bool) 
proof (state): depth 0

this:
  (Q::bool) /\ (P::bool)

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. P /\ Q /\ P
variables:
  P, Q :: bool
```

I see no sign that the subgoal has been proved. Or, the fact that the `have` statement is the same as in the `this` register should remind me that it is proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the subgoals in the output panel correspond to the subgoals of the context. In this case, the context is the one of the complete lemma, beginning with `proof -`. In this context, there is only one subgoal, which is the lemma to be proved.

When you state your intermediate property with `have`, the system doesn't verify anything with respect to the goals, and once it's proved, it just gives you access to this property (through the names `this` and `qp`) because you have proved it with `by (rule conjI)` and the fact that there is no error means that it is proved.

On the other hand, when you state a property with `show`, the system verifies that this property with the eventual assumptions you've made (with `assume`) actually corresponds to one of the subgoals, and fails otherwise.

When it arrives to the `qed` command, it finally verifies that all the subgoals of the context have been proved.

Another way to write this proof is like this (I didn't checked it worked, but it should...) :

```
theory Propositional
imports Main
begin

lemma nj2: assumes p: P and q: Q shows "P ∧ (Q ∧ P)"
proof (rule conjI)
  from p show P by assumption
next
  from q p show "Q ∧ P" by (rule conjI)
qed
```

In this case, `proof (rule conjI)` creates 2 subgoals `P` and `Q ∧ P` and the Output panel should confirm this.